# Verification of Navier's theory of structures

Tags: reference-request, engineering

Jacques Heyman in his article [Truesdell and the History of the Theory of Structures](https://books.google.gr/books?id=6LO_U6T-HvsC&pg=PA15#v=onepage&q&f=false), mentions the following:

> The first full-scale tests on building frames were made in the 1920s
>   in London, and the results were, in the fullest sense of the word,
>   astounding. The internal stress resultants (in this case, bending
>   stresses in beams) that were measured in practice bore almost no
>   relation to those confidently calculated by the elastic (Navier)
>   designer. The investigators quickly found what was wrong; while the
>   equilibrium equations were obeyed, and the elastic equations of
>   deformation were found to be almost exact, the boundary conditions
>   used in the analysis did not represent reality. A small error in
>   manufacture, a tiny dimensional mismatch, an inevitable forcing
>   together of members during construction - all these led to a great
>   change in the values of internal stresses.

Where can I find more information about these astounding results?